# Integration of a polynomial function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a big integration to solve for which the code I have written is illustrated below

```
Integrate[(t^w1*WO + t^w2*WP)^(a1 - 1)*(t^w3*VO + t^w4*VP)^a2*
  t^(w1 - 1), {t, 0, 1}]
```

This is not getting solved in Mathematica. Should I try Numerical Integration or something else for solving this

Comment: Numerical integration will only work if all the variables except t aren't really variables and have been assigned constant numeric values. But if that is the case then you can just assign those values to your other variables and try Integrate again. Letting people know any other information you have about your problem may really help with getting you a good answer.

Comment: I want to find a particular functional form.. giving values of a1 and a2 solves the problem but for generic a1 and a2 it does not solve.

Comment: Please put that information ("a1 and a2 solves the problem") into your question rather than a comment.  Also, are all of the values Reals?  Are they all greater than zero?  Are only integer values of a1 and a2 of interest?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes putting on restrictions on the parameters will result in a nicer functional form that will then suggest what restrictions can be relaxed and still have a nice functional form.

Here is the "nicer" functional for when $w_1>0$, $w_2>0$, $w_3>0$, $w_4>0$, and both $a_1$ and $a_2$ are positive integers.

Using the binomial expansion (and the above restrictions) the integral can be written as

```
Sum[Binomial[a1 - 1, k1] WO^k1 WP^(a1 - 1 - k1)*
  Binomial[a2, k2] VO^k2 VP^(a2 - k2)*
  Integrate[t^(-1 + w1 + k1 w1 + (-1 + a1 - k1) w2 + k2 w3 + (a2 - k2) w4), {t, 0, 1}],
  {k1, 0, a1 - 1}, {k2, 0, a2}]
```

Performing the integration results in

```
result = Sum[Binomial[a1 - 1, k1] WO^k1 WP^(a1 - 1 - k1)*
  Binomial[a2, k2] VO^k2 VP^(a2 - k2)/((1 + k1) w1 + (-1 + a1 - k1) w2 + k2 w3 + a2 w4 - k2 w4),
  {k1, 0, a1 - 1}, {k2, 0, a2}]
```

An example:

```
result /. {a1 -> 2, a2 -> 3}
```

[image: result with a1=2 and a2=3]

But I don't know how successful relaxing the positive integer restriction on $a_1$ and $a_2$ will be.

Comment: No, you are correct in saying that positivity restrictions should be there. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How to identify such a box structure (use cell right click "Copy as plain text", please)

```
Graphics[
     Text["\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \
    \(1\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(w1\)]\)*WO + \
    \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(w2\)]\)*WP\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \
    \(a1 - 1\)]\)*(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(w3\)]\)*VO + \
    \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(w4\)]\)*VP\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \
    \(a2\)]\)*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(w1 - 1\)]\)\[DifferentialD]t \
    "], ImageSize -> {200, 30}]
```

[image: trivial integral by substitution]

The problem in Mathematica with definite integrals: It seems, they are thought for cases only, that have no trival indefinite integrals.

By inspection the variable is  s= t^w1 with differential ds == w1 t^(w1-1) ds. So the integral makes a good impression

```
    Subtract@@(
Integrate[dt (t^w1* WO + t^w2* WP)^(a1-1)*(t^w3* VO + t^w4* VP)^a2*t^(w1-1),s]/.
{t^w1 -> s,
 t^n_:1-> s^(n/w1),
 dt-> (1/w1)s^(1/w^1-1)ds }/.
{{s->1},{s->0}}/.
{0^_:>1,ds->1})//FullSimplify

Out= ((VO+VP)^a2 (-WP^(-1+a1)+(WO+WP)^(-1+a1)))/w1
```

Since  in general, an expression with arbitrary powers make no sense at all, this is only a demonstration of a guess for the case that the local integral with all arguments of powers positive has a closed definite algebraic expression.

Always one has to be aware of the fact, that an explicit power x^-1 as summand in an integral is an exception from the rule: integral of powers -> powers, with logs in the result. Rational and complex powers have to rewritten as exponentials, where powers by multiplication in the exponent is universally possible.

In these cases, the Mathematica search for and supply of the found applicable domain descriptions for the free constants is lost in the forest of trees, almost always with probability 1.

Or, as most mathematicians got it the hard way: Everybody can learn to differentiate, but integration is a kind of pure art. Dates back to Plato.

To answer the question in the comment, here the commented version

In

```
Subtract@@
(Integrate[
dt (t^w1*WO+t^w2*WP)^(a1-1)*(t^w3*VO+t^w4*VP)^a2*t^(w1-1),s]/.
{t^w1->s,t^n_:1->s^(n/w1),dt->(1/w1)s^(1/w^1-1)ds}/.
{{s->1},{s->0}}/.
{0^_:>1,ds->1})//FullSimplify

((VO+VP)^a2 (-WP^(-1+a1)+(WO+WP)^(-1+a1)))/w1
```

the replacement procedure is expanded as

```
{t^w1 -> s,
(* the substitution  Solve[t^w1==s,t yields t-> s^(1/w1), to be used for ]*)
 t^n_ : 1 -> s^(n/w1), (*with exponent product, that's false, generally, but works for all positive Reals  as bases and exponents *) 
dt -> (1/w1) s^(1/w^1 - 1) ds , 
(* I resorted after long to go back to Leibniz, Stiltjes \
and Lebesgue and carry the measure of integration dx through all 
integrals at no cost but with great benefits *)}
```

Comment: “Definite integration is hard” could be stated in four words (proof by inspection).

Comment: Can you explain to me how and why you replaced the other powers of "t"